How can I declare bidirectional one to one relation in Prisma?
I have two models, Ingreso y Gasto, one Ingreso can reference to one Gasto by the ID or not (NULL), and one Gasto can reference to one Ingreso by the ID or not too (NULL).
I have tried to declare the relation in the two models like this:
model Ingreso {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

  idEgreso Int?    @unique @map("id_egreso")
  egreso   Egreso? @relation(fields: [idEgreso], references: [id])

  @@map("ingresos")
}

model Egreso {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

  idIngreso Int?     @unique @map("id_ingreso")
  ingreso   Ingreso? @relation(fields: [idIngreso], references: [id])

  @@map("egresos")
}

but it gives me this error:
Error parsing attribute "@relation": The relation fields egreso on Model Ingreso and ingreso on Model Egreso both provide the references argument in the @relation attribute. You have to provide it only on one of the two fields.

You should paste code, not images of code.

Got it, edited, thanks
